# SAML SSO with Zendesk and openam

Tags: java, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, openam, zendesk

I am trying SSO between my application and `zendesk`. I am using `openam` for this purpose. Suppose app is deployed as `app.myapp.com`. And I want to have SSO feature with zendesk, whose URL could be something like  `accountname.zendesk.com`. How do I setup openam configurations?

Whatever I have read in documentation is that, there should be a server with openam installed on it. And this will serve as Hosted Identity Provider. Now zendesk is going to be a service provider. This will be remote service provider. So how do I set this up? Should there be another instance of openam acting as remote service provider?

Comment: Zendesk acts as a SAML service provider directly so there is no need for an OpenAM based SP. 

You app either must implement a SAML SP as well or you mix OpenAM's proprietary SSO feature (using cookies and agents) with SAML (standards based Web SSO without the need for cookies).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried configuring `openam` for 2 days, but openam documents are too abstract and I couldn't get it to work. Then I tried SSO using JWT i.e. `JSON Web Token`. Now `Single sign on` between my application and `Zendesk` is working fine.